# How to solve $\sin (x) + \sin( x+y) =y$?

Tags: algebra-precalculus, taylor-expansion

A friend of mine asked how to lower and raise a constant line on the x-y axis as a function of sines and cosines. That is where I found that $$\sin(x) + \sin(x+y) = y $$ would do the trick if I found a function $y$ that works. My first instinct was to solve the equation but it seems like a rather difficult problem and I was unable to do so (although maybe I am wrong) My second thought was that, given that I already have a function for $y$, maybe approximating it with a Taylor series would work.

So far, working out the implicit derivatives and then solving for $y'$ has been a huge problem efficiency-wise. I was wondering if there is a quicker method to solve this problem or in case there isn't, is there an implicit derivative calculator online that will help me do this faster?

Comment: it sounds like representing parallel lines with a changing coefficients using sine,cosine

Comment: maybe you could elaborate a little on what exactly your original problem is.

Comment: @user159517 I am trying to isolate $y$, I simply want to express $y$ in terms of $x$, the original problem was to find a function that used only sines and cosines to produce a constant line with slope 0, but I think that it is much more interesting to simply isolate $y$ in terms of $x$, even if it is an infinite series.

Comment: You could never find an exact function in terms of x or y however the interesting thing is that all points on the implcit function can be expressed in a closed form. If you check wolfram alpha and type "sin(x)+sin(x+a)=a" you will find four general solutions to $x$.

Comment: @GuachoPerez Are you allowed to use arcsin for raising a constant line?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I am not sure what you mean in  the first question by "raising a constant line" in terms of $\sin$ or $\cos$. You could just use $a$ in $y=\arcsin{\left(\sin(a)\right)}$ so as $a$ increases, the line raises at a constant rate.

If you want to take only $x$ and $y$-values then shifting a constant line is impossible. Only a constant number in the form of $a$ can shift $x$ and $y$ values; not $x$ and $y$ values themselves. If you take $x^2$ there is no way you shift its vertex from $(0,0)$ to $(a,0)$ without changing $x^2$ to $(x-a)^2$.

For the second part of your question, which is now unrelated to the first part, you cannot to solve $\sin(x+y)+\sin(x)=y$ since one of $y$ variables is free from the sine brackets.
However you can find solutions in terms of $x$ but it very difficult to find by hand. On computer I replaced $y$ with $a$ so wolfram alpha could register a solution as shown [here](http://www.wolframalpha.com/input/?i=sin%28x-a%29%2Bsin%28x%29%3Da) (look under "solutions to $x$").

I was also able to find a taylor series as I have found using mathematica. I chose $(\pi,0)$ because the curve was less steep in that region so the rate of convergence can be quick. I found the radius of convergence was near $({\pi/4,3\pi/4})$.

$$[\sin(x+y)+\sin(y)=y]\approx-(x-\pi)+\frac{\left(x-\pi\right)^{3}}{(3!)(2)}-\frac{\left(x-\pi\right)^{5}}{(5!)(2)}+\frac{(x-{\pi})^7}{2(7!)}+\frac{17(x-{\pi})^9}{(9!)}$$

More coefficients of the taylor series can be found [here](https://mathematica.stackexchange.com/questions/103650/how-to-find-the-derivative-value-at-pi-0-for-this-implcit-function-n-time?noredirect=1#comment281407_103650). To find even more coefficients you should get mathematica and for simply graphing functions you can use [desmos](https://www.desmos.com/calculator).

The most exciting thing I found is that $\sin(x+y)+\sin(x)=y$ cannot be solved explcitly for $x$ or $y$ as one equation but has all points that can be described as a closed form.

Answer (score 0):

We add an answer which is still an implicit function but in another way .
$$\sin x +\sin (x+y)=(1+\cos y)\sin x+\sin y\cos x=y$$  Put $A=\sqrt{(1+\cos y)^2+(\sin y)^2}=\sqrt{2(1+\cos y)}$ so $A$ is the hypotenusa of a triangle whose legs are $\sin y$ and $1+\cos y$; dividing by $A$ it follows $$\frac{1+\cos y}{A}\sin x+\frac{\sin y}{A}\cos x=\frac{y}{A}$$
and puting  $\sin \theta=\frac {\sin y}{A}$ we have $$\sin x \cos \theta+\cos x \sin \theta=\sin (x+\theta)=\frac{y}{A}$$

Thus $$\color{red}{y=\sqrt{2(1+\cos y)}\sin (x+\theta)}$$ where $$ \theta=\arcsin \left(\frac{\sin y}{\sqrt{2(1+\cos y)}}\right)$$

---

HINT.-The equation being a trascendental one, it seems doesn't matter of a closed form or getting $y=f(x)$. An approximation could be get solving several times $$\sin x +\sin (x+a_i)=a_i$$ (which is not a nice gift) and interpolating some manner, particularly polynomials, the resulting points $(x_i,a_i)$.

On the other hand some points of the function can be easily get, for example, when you make $$\sin x +\sin (x -\frac{\pi}{3})=-\frac{\pi}{3}\qquad (*)$$ you have the function $3\sin x-\sqrt 3\cos x$ at the LHS and this function has its minimun equal to $-3.464$ which is less than $-\frac{\pi}{3}$ hence the equation $(*)$ has solution; making
 $\tan \frac x2=t$  you can obtain an exact solution $(x,y)$. But this exactly calculated point is not important for the viewpoint of interpolation, here suggested

Comment: I checked your exact solution and the arcsin is undefined. If you graph the implicit function there is no value of $-\frac{\pi}{2}$.

Comment: You are right: the expression is equal to $\sin x-\cos x$ so is never equal to $-\frac {\pi}{2}$;  this was an oversight on my part. Anyway, it could be other values for $a_i$ with exact solution, which is purely "anecdotic". Which stay valid although embarrassing, I think is a possible interpolation. Thank you very much for your remark.